# How to avoid mocking interface default methods with EasyMock?

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have an interface having default methods. These refer to non-default methods and I want to mock only those.

Example:

```
public interface InterfaceWithDefaultMethod {

    public String getTestString();
    
    public default String getCombinedString() {
        return "Test" + getTestString();
    }
}
```

I only want to mock `getTestString()`

`EasyMock.mock(InterfaceWithDefaultMethod.class)` does produce a mock class where all methods are mocked, i.e. `getCombinedString` is not being delegated to `getTestString()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by creating a dummy implementation of the interface and to partial-mock this dummy implementation.

```
private static class InterfaceMock implements InterfaceWithDefaultMethod {

    @Override
    public String getTestString() {
        return null;
    }
        
}

private InterfaceWithDefaultMethod testedInterface;

@Before
public void setup() {
    testedInterface = createMockBuilder(InterfaceMock.class)
        .addMockedMethod("getTestString")
        .createMock();
    resetToNice(testedInterface);
    expect(testedInterface.getTestString()).andStubReturn("First");
    replay(testedInterface);
}
```

Comment: Cant you just do a partial mock of the interface class?

Comment: I don't thin it is supported. But it should. It's a good feature request to add to the project.

Comment: @GhostCat: No you can't partial mock an interface, only classes. It was the first thing I tried :-).

Comment: You don't even have to add the method to the helper class, you can just make the class abstract. Creating partial mocks from abstract classes works and then you just have to use `addMockMethod()` for the interface methods, that you don't want to test, but that need expected behaviour.